# cassandra: implement global order

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm trying to create event store for event sourcing with cassandra and understand how it'll fit for this usage. 
Keyspace contains one table:

```
CREATE TABLE commits (
  stream_id text, 
  version bigint, 
  'timestamp' timestamp, 
  commit blob,
  PRIMARY KEY(stream_id, version)
);
```

I need 3 essential operations:

- Append commit to this table. This one is easy, as I'm ok with single writer per `stream_id`.
- Get all commits for some `stream_id` and bounded by `version`. This is also not hard, but I think performance can be improved somehow. Current implementation: 
  `SELECT * FROM commits WHERE stream_id = ? AND version >= ? AND version <= ? ORDER BY version;`
- And the hardest one that I can't implement: get **all** commits bounded by `timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?` or some other global sequence number.

I understand that global ordering is an evil in distributed system. This query will not be used often. Even better will be to use some counter instead of timestamp.
How can I implement this requirement in cassandra?

Comment: ever figured this out?